# Show breakpoints when debugging Matlab

Tags: debugging, matlab, gud

I am using [matlab-emacs](http://matlab-emacs.sourceforge.net/) to debug a matlab script from inside of emacs with GUD.  Everything seems to be working as expected except that I don't see any breakpoint indicators in the fringe.

This is important to me for two reasons:

1. It is nice to easily see where all of the breakpoints are in the code. It makes it much easier to know what to expect when I "continue."
2. It lets me toggle breakpoints on and off. When the breakpoint indicator is there, I can check for it in code, and know whether I should toggle the breakpoint on or off.

Is there a way to get breakpoint indicators for Matlab debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless some thing has changed with newer versions of MatLab, short answer is you cannot (MaTLaB 2011b here). Eric Ludlam, maintainer of matlab-emacs, does say so [here in the matlab-emacs mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/matlab-emacs/mailman/message/28872261/). MatLab lost an undocumented API which allowed it to show icons for breakpoints with select versions of GUD.